# Priorities in a SELECT query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is probably a bad example, but I think it's quite simple.
Let's say a web search engine (e.g. [Google](http://www.google.com)) is retrieving results (links to websites) of a search performed by the user and it's supposed to order them according to a given priority of languages **and** countries at the same time. Say,

Language priorities

```
 1. English
 2. Spanish
 3. Italian
 ...
```

Country priorities

```
 1. USA
 2. England
 3. Canada
 4. Spain
 5. Mexico
 ...
```

So, the result would be something ordered like

```
Websites in english and from the USA
Websites in spanish and from the USA or in english and from England

...

Websites in italian and from Mexico (?).
```

A query like

```
SELECT url FROM websites
WHERE (
 language = english
 OR language = spanish
 OR language = italian
 ) AND (
 country = USA
 OR country = England
 OR country = Canada
 OR country = Spain
 OR country = Mexico)
```

obviously wouldn't work because it provides a condition, not a priority. Using `ORDER BY language` or `ORDER BY timezone` wouldn't work either because it orders it alphabetically. So, how is the best way to go about this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the languages and countries are in their own tables and that the websites table references those two, you `order by` the two fields that hold the priority of each table..

something like

```
SELECT 
    wesbites.url 
FROM 
    websites 
    INNER JOIN languages on websites.languageId = languages.id
    INNER JOIN countries on websites.countryId = countries.id
ORDER BY
    languages.priority,
    countries.priority
```

Comment: +1, but I would generalize the `ORDER BY` clause as `ORDER BY expression(languages.priority, countries.priority)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a thought experiment, so the answer is a big, "It depends." If you *really* want to complicate things, then you would also be aware of that person's geolocation (or at least geopreference for those crazy ex-pats) and language.

At any rate, you'd at least have a many-to-many relationship between language and country (for example, USA would have English and Spanish). Then you would sort by language preference and *then* country (because as an English speaker, I'm much more interested in English sites from the UK than I am in Spanish sites from the USA).

So, you'd have a URL table then a Country table and then a Language table. You could have a rank in your Language table if you actually had user preference--Google wouldn't do this, since they're international. You'd have countries listed by Lat and Long, and then you could do simple distance calculations in your order by to get to the nearest countries as you. Or, if you wanted custom relationships, you could give a Country-Country mapping table that would map countries to its cousins (e.g.-US to UK).

But in reality, Google doesn't do this. They search for the relevance of your query (they can parse what language it is based on their substantial translation engine), and then feed those back to you based on a whole slew of variables. They don't do this with simple relational database modelling, but rather complex statistical analysis.

As conjecture (I don't work at Google), your links get a relevance to query score and a relevance to you score. Results are then ordered by the summation of the two, descending. It calculates those things very fast based on statistical models it already has in place (it simply plugs in your values and gets the result--data mining models can do this prediction incredibly fast, as it takes much longer to compile the model).

Answer (score 0):

Your tables will have to define those priorities, so the language table will have a priority column and your country table will also have a priority column, then you would use those in your order by clause. Is there a restriction where you can't add those columns?